# How can I calculate this Series that are a subtraction of two square roots in denominator?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I go about calculating the following Series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right )$$

I am not allowed to use integrals, btw.

Also, what type of series are these? I know that the first one is a divergent Dirichelet series, but not sure about the second.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something similar to the "[telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)".

If you look at the partial sum $s_N$, there are lots of "cancellations". Then you can use $\lim_{N\to\infty}s_N$ to get the result of your series.

Specifically,
$$
s_N=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+2}}
$$

Comment: OH!!! I feel stupid for not trying the partial sums.....